# NServiceBus - using DBSubscriptionStorageConfig, but SQl server subscription table doesn't show any record

Tags: nservicebus

After adding section for SQL Database to handle subscriptions, My subscriber config looks like this

;initial catalog=NServiceBus;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>

I changed the endpoint class as follows

```
class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server , IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        NServiceBus.Configure.With()
            .Log4Net()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .DBSubcriptionStorage();
    }
}
```

When I fire up the application, where subscribers automatically subscribe, I don't see any entries in the subscription DB. Also I don't see any error reported by the application... Anything I am missing in the config file...

Appreciate any help...

Answer (score 2):

When using the builtin roles like As_aServer the role config takes precedence. So in your case the db sub.storage will only be used if you use As_aPublisher + run in the "production" profile.

Comment: Ok, So I am building the publisher with following config

Comment: class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            NServiceBus.Configure.With()
                .Log4Net()
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .XmlSerializer()
                .UnicastBus()
                .ImpersonateSender(false)
                .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(true)
                .DBSubcriptionStorage();
        }
    }

Comment: Make sure that you start the host with the production profile ie. "NServiceBus.Production" passed as a cmd-line item

Comment: You should also be able to remove your custom config and use:  EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher{} since that will be equivalent to what you're doing your self